# Can't uninstall vim

Tags: vim, linux-mint

I've got a problem with vim deinstallation. I've done `sudo apt-get remove` on vim, vim-common, vim-tiny and actually anything starting with 'vim' in the package list, but still can run vim from command line. It doesn't show up in packages list but still works. I can't understand how it is even possible... How can I remove it completely?

Comment: Maybe `vim` command that you are running is actually an alias to `vi`. What is the output of `type vim`?

Comment: It runs the latest vim version which I installed from source before.

Comment: There's your answer: if you installed from source, then there is no package that contains it. Try `which vim` and destroy the offending binary. Or just don't type `vim`.

Comment: Software installed from source might be impossible to delete through package management systems. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely what about `make uninstall`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

vim which appears in package list is not the same as the one I installed from source. I manually removed 'vim' directory from `/usr/share`, `/usr/local/share` and `/usr/local/bin` and now it seems there is no trace of it left.